# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes when doing any kind of videochat

Tags: 14.04, video, skype, video-conversion, google-hangouts

I have a Dell notebook, with a processor Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3700 @ 1.60GHz × 4, 64 bits architecture, 3,8 GiB memory, and Intel® HD Graphics (Cherryview) graphics.

The problem is that every time I want to do videochat (using Google Hangouts, Skype, Facebook call or whatever) my computer freezes after some time (in average I would say ~20 minutes).

My Ubuntu version is 14.04. I thought this problem could be cause because 14.04 is already a somewhat old version of Ubuntu.

The question is, should I do the effort to update my Ubuntu to at least 16.04 to try to solve this problem? I know it could be related, but it may not, and if that's the case, I'd have updated my Ubuntu in vain.

Any suggestion on what to do would be highly appreciated. Also please tell me if there is some detail to clarify that I forgot.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend to update at least to 16.04. 14.04 not only old system, it have ancient software, kernel, drivers. For an LTS the software often already old when the system just released, and then as a bonus LTS fixes packages at specific versions *(with a few exceptions like browsers)*, and only backports security patches. It's more suited for server usage, than to users. So you might say, your experience is very crippled. And since you happen to have such a serious problem, I think it's a nice time to update at least to 16.04 or even later.

Comment: Hmm okay, you're right I think. Looking at your profile raised the following question: do you think that switching to ArchLinux will make it more likely that videocalls will start working? I was thinking about switching anyways, so I might do it, at least to try.

Comment: I can't know about the calls *(but it should)*, but it'll surely fix the crash. It's a serious problem, that I doubt could've went unnoticed. Regarding Archlinux — it depends on how experienced user you're, because it doesn't even have an installer. Installation is, basically: 1. Format a partition, 2. unpack a minimal system, 3. chroot, 4. install packages, 5. create a user, 6. install a bootloader, 7. enable services *(at least Display Manager)*, 8. reboot . I'd rather recommend Fedora. I didn't use it myself, but they're all over the news, and I see Red Hat developers literally everywhere.